# Determine CSV size before inserting the next batch of data

Tags: java, oracle, csv

I am working on a feature where I need to fetch the data from Oracle table and each row of table is mapped to a Java object. so I will be having the List of records and I need to create a CSV file with this data.

Different scenarios to consider here:

1. There is going to be millions of records and I will be fetching the data in 10k batches.
2. Each batch of 10k records will be appended to csv.

Restriction:

1. The CSV file should not exceed more than 100 MB.
2. If at any point, the size is more than 100 MB , I should create a new CSV file.

Question:

1. How can I make sure I dont insert records once CSV file size has reached 100 MB ?
2. Suppose I have list of records which contains 10k employee objects and I somehow calculate the size of this list as 1MB. So if I put these records in csv, will the size of csv will also be 1 MB?

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following solution.
 First of all,  we should not read millions of records from Oracle in a single query. The Oracle table should be partitioned by date, month, year, or any other criteria.  You can throttle the number of records and write into a file.

Secondly, the csv file size. Instead of looking at the csv file size before appending into a csv file, you can look at the size of the results object in java and determine how many records you want to append in that batch append.

Comment: If you read question again, I have clearly mentioned that I will be fetching records in 10k batches and not in one shot. Also regarding CSV size, the question is , if I calculate size of 10k list of employee object as 1MB and if I put these in csv, will CSV size will be 1MB or it would be different ? Because this way I will get to know whether appending this in csv will exceed 100 MB or not.